# Limiting character count between two limits

Tags: php, validation, if-statement, error-handling

I have a validation if statement that checks two things primarily. First : to see if a drop down box named "why" is empty, if it is empty it will shoot an error to the front end stating we need you to give us a proper reason. That works fine. Now I have a second condition saying that if for any reason the value in the "why" drop down box is 'Other" and if the comments box is empty then that will shoot another error. Now those two work fine, if its empty it will say 'Please explain the nature of your visit in the comments box!'

my problem is that I am trying to have it so that the comments box is between 15 to 45 characters long. I have been fideling with this signinpage.php validation for about 20 some hours to make it exactly how I want and I just can't get to where I want it. Any help would be lovely!

```
if(empty($why)) {
            $errors[] = 'Please make sure to select the proper reasoning for your vistit today!';
    } 
        elseif ($why ==='Other' && empty($comments)) {
            $errors[] = 'Please explain the nature of your visit in the comments box!';

        if (strlen($comments) < 15) {
            $errors[] = 'Your explaination is short, please revise!';
    }
        if(strlen($comments) > 45) {
            $errors[] = 'Your explaintion is to long, please revise!';
    }
    }
```

Indented:

```
if(empty($why)) {
    $errors[] = 'Please make sure to select the proper reasoning for your vistit today!';
} 
elseif ($why ==='Other' && empty($comments)) {
    $errors[] = 'Please explain the nature of your visit in the comments box!';

    if (strlen($comments) < 15) {
        $errors[] = 'Your explaination is short, please revise!';
    }
    if(strlen($comments) > 45) {
        $errors[] = 'Your explaintion is to long, please revise!';
    }
}
```

Comment: Why be so rigid with comment length? Frankly, it looks okay, does it just error? Does it let you post longer/shorter ones?

Comment: If you simply indent and format your code correctly in the future (you really need to get used to that), you will not have problems like this.

Comment: I keep hearing this from people. Where can find examples of proper indenting? I'm sorry for the stupid question just kinda new to this and I'm being rushed to finish this system without the proper know-how

Comment: @RixhersAjazi, don't look for a standard, just do it yourself. All you have to do is indent the code so it looks good to you. For example, if you indented this code, you would indent the comments check to appear inside the `elseif` part, and it would then be obvious to you what was going on. Indenting is a style choice, and in principle, all you have to do is put enough spaces before a line of code to properly align it with the others.

Comment: Alright. Thanks for the heads up! ty.

Comment: @RixhersAjazi, I added an indented version of your code inside your question. Does it look cleaner to you, and, more importantly, does it make it obvious what the problem is?

Comment: yes completely. I see that the additional if statements were not inside the elseif statement. thank you

Comment: @RixhersAjazi, great! Indenting is a very good practice, that takes almost no effort whatsoever, yet it comes with many advantages, such as making the code (much) more readable and understandable by both yourself and others, and can prevent many such problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you copied and pasted this correctly, then your brackets are messing things up.  Put all your comment validation into a single section that gets checked ONLY if `$why==="Other"`.

```
if(empty($why))
    $errors[] = 'Please make sure to select the proper reasoning for your vistit today!';
elseif ($why ==='Other'){
    if(empty($comments))
        $errors[] = 'Please explain the nature of your visit in the comments box!';
    else{
        if (strlen($comments) < 15)
            $errors[] = 'Your explaination is short, please revise!';
        if(strlen($comments) > 45)
            $errors[] = 'Your explaintion is to long, please revise!';
    }
}
```

Comment: So I guess what I was doing wrong was that I was treating the if statements as separate parts not as a part of the elseif statement?

Comment: @RixhersAjazi, you had the `if (strlen($comments) ...` part inside the `if (empty($comments) ...` condition. "if the comments string is empty, then, let's see if it contains less than 15 characters or more than 45". It doesn't, you just established the fact that it's empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(empty($why)) {
        $errors[] = 'Please make sure to select the proper reasoning for your vistit today!';
} 
elseif ($why ==='Other' && empty($comments)) {
        $errors[] = 'Please explain the nature of your visit in the comments box!';
}
elseif($why === 'Other'){
    if (strlen($comments) < 15) {
        $errors[] = 'Your explaination is short, please revise!';
    }
    if(strlen($comments) > 45) {
        $errors[] = 'Your explaintion is to long, please revise!';
    }
}
```

You were including your check of the length inside a check that required that comments be empty.